# Accessing all comments, on all posts, that a current_user has commented on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

This is sorta related to [another question I asked recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4420519/advice-on-how-to-send-email-to-multiple-users-based-on-an-association). But before I implement that question's answer, I wanted to try and do this in a more simple way.

I have built a ruby on rails application that allows users to track their workouts. Workouts also have the ability to be commented on. In my dashboard view for `current_user` I am trying to fish out all comments from workouts that current_user has commented on. Here is an example:

User A creates a workout and User B comments on it. User C comments on User A's workout. I want User B to see User C's comment in their dashboard view.

What is the most efficient way to loop through comments and pull out all comments from workouts that a user has commented on? It's like I want to say this but obviously this won't work:

```
<% current_user.comments.workouts.comments.each do |comment| %>
```

I have been experimenting with named_scopes for this but can't seem to figure it out. The associations are as you would expect.

```
User has_many :workouts
User has_many :comments

Workout belongs_to :user
Workout has_many :comments

Comment belongs_to :user
Comment belongs_to :workout
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you'd probably want to organize the comments according the the workouts that the user had commented on (as opposed to one long undifferentiated string of comments without any context), first I'd suggest using a :has_many => through to aggregate the workouts that the user had commented on, something roughly like (untested, obviously):

```
has_many :commented_workouts, :through => :comments, :class_name => 'Workout', :source =>  :workout, :uniq => true, :order => "created_at desc"
```

Then you could display the comments in your erb something like:

```
<% current_user.commented_workouts.each do |workout| %>
  <%= workout.name %>:
  <% workout.comments.each do |comment| %>
    <%= comment.text %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

EDIT: you could also do:

```
<% current_user.commented_workouts.each do |workout| %>
  <% workout.comments.sort{|x,y| x.created_at <=> y.created_at }.each do |comment| %>
    <%= comment.user.name %> just commented on <%= workout.title %>:
    <div><%= comment.text %></div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

EDIT: Or like so (note the limit added to the array):

```
class User
  def watched_comments
    commented_workouts.map(&:comments).flatten.sort{|x,y| x.created_at <=> y.created_at }
  end
end

# and in the erb: 

<% current_user.watched_comments[0,10].each do |comment| %>
  <%= comment.user.name %> just commented on <%= comment.workout.title %>:
  <div><%= comment.text %></div>
<% end %>
```

There's a bit of nasty n+1 query fu going on here that might not be real performant tho. Alternately you could try to get everything done in straight sql which would perform better. Something like (sql ninjas no doubt could do better):

EDIT: You can also add a 'limit' option directly in the SQL

```
has_many :watched_comments, :class_name => 'Comment', :finder_sql => 'select * from comments, workouts where comments.workout_id = workout.id and workouts.id in (select workouts.id from workouts, comments where workouts.id = comments.id and comments.user_id = #{id}) order by comments.created_at desc limit 10'
```

Comment: Ok this works but I actually do want the single stream of comments. For instance I would want the put to read `UserA just commented on workouttitle` Could the code be adjusted to do that?

Comment: Oh and have them listed by `:order => "created_at DESC"`

Comment: This still isn't quite what I was trying to do. I really want all the comments, regardless of which workout they are on, to be listed by `comment.created_at DESC`. Can that be done through this method?

Comment: It's still grouping the comments by workout. Sorry to be a pain here, I really do appreciate your help.

Comment: The more I look at this the more I think it has to do with the first line of your edited code above. That fact that we are calling all workouts first would seem to leave no option but to group by workout. I don't know if that makes sense. You knows a lot more than me at this.

Comment: The new edit seems to work but the `:limit` feature doesn't seem to work correctly as when appending that to the `has_many` line it is limiting the workouts it pulls in, not the total comment limit. Any ideas?

Comment: Try adding the limit directly in the sql.

Comment: If you don't want to use the SQL version (which I prefer), you could just limit the array with standard Ruby array notation. (see the new edits)

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
<% workouts = []
   current_user.comments.each do |comment|
     unless workouts.include? comment.workout.id  # prevents duplicates
       workouts << comment.workout.id
       comment.workout.comments.each do |comment|
         # now comment refers to all comments for that workout
         puts "#{comment.user.name} says #{comment.text}"
       end
     end  
   end %>
```

Essentially, you grab the workout associated with each of their comments and display all the comments for them.

**For extra homework ;)**

1. Flag their own comment with something special

Comment: Won't that cause duplicates? (Let me put it this way... If Workout A has 2 comments by User1, then Workout A's comments will be looped through twice!)

Comment: So I am having a hard time getting this to work. It is not throwing any errors just no output.

Comment: Seems like Dave Sims is giving you closer to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

   has_many :workouts
   has_many :comments

   def workouts_on_which_i_commented
     comments.map{|x|x.workout}.uniq
   end

   def comment_stream
     workouts_on_which_i_commented.map do |w|
       w.comments
     end.flatten.sort{|x,y| y.created_at <=> x.created_at}
   end

end
```

Comment: This seems to be working nicely. How would I limit the number of records like: `:limit => 3` type of thing? Also, the order `created_at DESC`. ?

Comment: What do you want to limit? The net number of comments in comment_stream? the number of workouts you are connected to? You can use the "take" method at the end of the array to limit the number of results returned from the array. The sorting above is based on created_at already, change it if you want to sort differently.